# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer when trying to run spark job in zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

## 1.Summarizing the problem

I have build zeppelin from the source code by running the below command.
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-2.3 -Pscala-2.11
The build was successful.

Launched apache zeppelin on kubernetes cluster and could see zeppelin-server starts perfectly fine.
but when trying to run a spark notebook the spark interpreter pod goes into completed/succeded state with below errors in the logs from spark-interpreter.log

WARN [2020-03-06 00:42:37,683] ({main} Logging.scala[logWarning]:87) - Failed to load org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer

## 2.Describe what you’ve tried

I did not find any resolution so could not try any solution to this problem yet.

any suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue and was able to resolve by adding --jars with interpreter and spark jars in the zeppelin-env.sh script but later stuck into different issue.

Now that interpreter is starting but unable to launch executors.

Below is the error message, if anybody would like to provide any inputs, would appreciate it.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/resolution/DependencyResolutionException

Thank you.